# How to read GB2312 encoded text files using Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, character-encoding, gb2312

My app needs to read text files encoded in GB2312. Here is the current code.

```
 SGFString = try String(contentsOf:path)
```

It throws an exception.

> couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be
>   determined.

While looking into the String.Encoding values, there is no GB2312. What would be the best way to read the GB2312 text files?

Thanks
Ray

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41477709/6541007) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29122270/6541007) can be some help. As you know, GB-18030 is an upper compatible standard including GB-2312.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for OOPer's help. I copied some of the code from the links, now it works.
Here is the code:

```
extension String.Encoding {
    static let gb_18030_2000 = String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.GB_18030_2000.rawValue)))
}

Gb2312String =  try String(contentsOf:path, encoding:String.Encoding.gb_18030_2000)
```