# Swift 3.1: String.Encoding(rawValue: ) run incorrectly in an iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, encode

I wrote some code in a **command-line-tool application**, and it run correctly.
But when I brought it to my **iOS application**, it went wrong.

The essentil code is:

```
let foo = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.GBK_95.rawValue))
let bar = String.Encoding(rawValue: foo)
print("foo=\(foo)")
print("bar=\(bar)")
```

When I run these code in a **command-line-tool application**, I got:

```
foo=2147485233
bar=Chinese (GBK)
```

When I run these code in a **iOS application**, I got:

```
foo=2147485233
bar=
```

It seems amazing that the code got different result in two environment.
Does bar get an empty Enumeration value?How can I resolve it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well...I got help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944769/how-to-read-gb2312-encoded-text-files-using-swift-3-0/41990100#41990100)

Use GB_18030_2000 instead.

`let encoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.GB_18030_2000.rawValue)))`